# Use javascript to go to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Script

```
function showcontent(language){
    $('#content').html('Introduction to ' + language + ' language');
}
$(function(){
    showcontent('java');
});
```

Content part:

```
<div id="content" region="center" border="true" title="" style="overflow:auto;padding:10px">

</div>
```

Selector bar:

```
<div title="Subscriber List Management" iconCls="icon-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showcontent('list/add.php')">Add List</a></li> //not works
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showcontent('test')">View List</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the javascript that displays language I selected in a "content" panel.  How can I modify it so that instead of `$('#content').html('Introduction to ' + language + ' language');` the "content" displays an HTML/PHP page instead of some text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AJAX $.load(), such as:

```
$('#content').load('somefile.html')
```

and then you can add your language variable after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. And i found that the css file redirect have some difference in this case.

Comment: For example
my folder is look like this
root: index.php <==where the "content" at,
,styles,member:add.php,
When i load the page in member folder, the css will depend on index.php but not add.php

Comment: @user782104 yes, the load function strips off the everything but the `<body>`by default, and you can narrow that with `$('#content').load('somefile.html #someid')`

Comment: Thanks. it only have <body>content between</body>? but I have a lot of css and js defined .

Comment: You can load the css on the fly by finding it with a jquery selector and then follow similar instructions at [link](http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2009/09/how-to-load-javascript-and-css-dynamically-with-jquery/)

Comment: It seems that the css will apply to all the part of the index.php instead of add.php ("content" part) as well. Is it mean i have to redefine the css to make it strict to the "content" part?

Comment: Looks like it, which I would suggest is best practice, anyway.